# a minoration of $P(X>x)$ with $X~N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, then to show that for $x > 0$,

$$P(X>x) \geq \frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x}}\times \frac{\exp(-x^2/2)}{(2\pi)^{1/2}}$$

I know that $$ \frac{\exp(-x^2/2)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\left (\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^3}\right )
< P(X>x)
$$, but i dont know how to continue.

Comment: could you please update the question with your own thoughts on the problem and we will be happy to guide you further.

Comment: I know that $$ \frac{\exp(-x^2/2)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\left (\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^3}\right )
< P(X>x)
$$, but i dont know how to continue.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function